# Is this argument a deduction or induction?

Tags: logic

I'm reading the book *A Concise Introduction to Logic (12th edition)*, and they say that this is a **deduction**:

```
Gabriel is a wolf.
Gabriel has a tail.
Therefore, Gabriel’s tail is the tail of a wolf.
```

Is that correct? It is not only probable that Gabriel's tail is a wolf's tail? He may can have a cat's tail because of a transplant. This conclusion necessarily follows?

Comment: Yes, that is a classic deduction. It only relies on premises (definitions) and logic, not observations or any other extranea. By definition, the tail on a wolf is the tail of a wolf; the wolf possesses that tail; it is the wolf's tail, regardless of how he came by it.

Comment: With "a wolf tail" it'd be induction.

Answer (score 13):

Even if it was (by transplant) "a cat's tail" (*phenomenological*), it would still be Gabriel's tail (i.e. the tail **of Gabriel**, *possessive/as a predicate*), and since Gabriel **is** a wolf, it would be the tail **of a wolf**, namely of Gabriel the wolf (*possessive/as a predicate*).

Therefore, it is a clean deduction, though perhaps a bit clumsy in the formulation.

**Addition including the comment of @quen_tin:** The reason why the formulation is clumsy is that the fine differences between "tail of a wolf" and "wolf tail" make the difference between deduction and induction or possibly (as this is a single occurence) even more precise: [Abduction](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/abduction/).

Comment: +1 for mentioning abduction. Indeed, deducting that Gabriel's tail is that of a wolf is a deduction, but saying that all wolf as the same tail as Gabriel (a wolf tail) is clearly an abduction since you are generalizing from one example.

Answer (score 3):

It is a deduction, namely it's a deductive argument, put it in the standard form, although it isn't clear if it's valid and sound or not(to me it is) that doesn't mean that is not a deduction. Previous answers are trying to prove the validity and soundness of this deductive argument, but your question is, if it's a deduction, which it is.